# if f is riemann integrable is the floor function integrable？

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

If $f$ is a riemann integrable function over $[a,b]$ , is the floor function{f(x)} riemann integrable over $[a,b]$ ?

Here is what i've tried: i figured out that the discontinued points of {f(x)} don't always be the subset of f(x)'s. And i also can't construct a counterexample... So i don't have any ideas now:(

Comment: Oh i see...we can take https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function?wprov=sfsi1 with negative sign

Comment: You can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081052/continuous-function-changing-sign-on-cantor-set) for a continuous example, where $C$ is the fat Cantor set. In fact, I think the construction can be modified so as to create a $C^{\infty}$ example.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexamples have been discussed in the comments.

However, this *does* hold if we have the condition that $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is real-analytic.

If $f$ is constant, it's immediately clear. If $f$ is *not* constant, then note that $f$ is bounded, so the image of $f$ is a subset of $[-M,M]$ for $M>0$. There are finitely many integers in $[-M,M]$, so the set $S=\{x \in [a,b] : f(x) \in \mathbb{Z} \cap [-M,M] \}$ must also be finite. This is an immediate  consequence of Bolzano–Weierstrass  and the principle of permeance. But the discontinuities of $\lfloor f \rfloor$ are a subset of $S$ which means $f$ must have at most finitely many discontinuities, which implies Riemann integrability.